# Making a paypal button to checkout items in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

So coming from an angular background where I'm familiar doing a PayPal button, I'm unable to get it to work for React.js. What are methods to build the PayPal button component for react.js that works? Any suggestion would help greatly?

Comment: It is described here `https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout`  and example is given here for React.js https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md

Comment: @Panther thanks for the suggestion! Actually Paypal's document does not provide clear information as well as example (especially for react developers), it was a bit more difficult for me to create a react npm library for this. Please check my answer below for my newly created `react-paypal-express-checkout`

Comment: Have you also fixed this problem, otherwise please comment here some ideas. If this is also solved by my answer (or part/direction) of my answer, please consider an up-vote as well as an accept for my answer below, thanks

Comment: Anyone looking for an alternative, I have written a step by step guide to setup [React with Stripe and Express](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/).

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some codez?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has the same question: this concise [step-by-step guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-paypal-payment/) can be used to write up your own React component which uses the PayPal REST API.

In the below code fragment, note:

1. API loaded asynchronously and `isScriptLoad*` props to check load status
2. showButton to hold the state (can be rendered or not)
3. binding to DOM
4. `componentDidMount` vs `componentWillReceiveProps` to check loading status of API
5. Props to be passed to the componet to manage the transaction: total, currency, env, commit, client, onSuccess, onError, onCancel
6. `payment` and `authorize` methods to actually implement the transaction

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader';

class PaypalButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  showButton: false,
};

window.React = React;
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
const {
  isScriptLoaded,
  isScriptLoadSucceed
} = this.props;

if (isScriptLoaded && isScriptLoadSucceed) {
  this.setState({ showButton: true });
}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const {
  isScriptLoaded,
  isScriptLoadSucceed,
} = nextProps;

const isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore =
  !this.state.showButton &&
  !this.props.isScriptLoaded &&
  isScriptLoaded;

if (isLoadedButWasntLoadedBefore) {
  if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
    this.setState({ showButton: true });
  }
}
  }

  render() {
const {
  total,
  currency,
  env,
  commit,
  client,
  onSuccess,
  onError,
  onCancel,
} = this.props;

const {
  showButton,
} = this.state;

const payment = () =>
  paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
    transactions: [
      {
        amount: {
          total,
          currency,
        }
      },
    ],
  });

const onAuthorize = (data, actions) =>
  actions.payment.execute()
    .then(() => {
      const payment = {
        paid: true,
        cancelled: false,
        payerID: data.payerID,
        paymentID: data.paymentID,
        paymentToken: data.paymentToken,
        returnUrl: data.returnUrl,
      };

      onSuccess(payment);
    });

return (
  <div>
    {showButton && <paypal.Button.react
      env={env}
      client={client}
      commit={commit}
      payment={payment}
      onAuthorize={onAuthorize}
      onCancel={onCancel}
      onError={onError}
    />}
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default scriptLoader('https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js')(PaypalButton);
```